# Windows Server 2003 used as a Spam Relay

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, spam

We have a server running Windows Server 2003 and Matrix Control panel. We are continually used to relay spam, which fills the badmail folder and gets us blacklisted. The bad mail folder filled the c: drive last night and rendered the entire server unusable.

Matrix control panel generally sits on top of the windows services but for SMTP it uses its own service which seems extremely limited in config options.

The spammers are using one particular domain to bounce emails from, and the username part of the email address' that they are using is randomly generated so its not like they have a password for one of the genuine accounts.

What I would like to know is:

How are they able to send spam without a valid username and password?

Can I stop them?

Can I stop Bad Mails being saved on WinServer2003?

We are in the process of upgrading this ancient server but we need it to work for a few more weeks while the new one is prepared.

Thanks

Comment: Q: How are they able to send spam without a valid username and password? A: Your server is an open relay. Q: Can I stop them? A: Yes you can. Q: Can I stop Bad Mails being saved on WinServer2003? A: I believe so. Try setting the registry entries described in this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884068

Comment: I saw that support article but unfortunately for me this server is not running exchange. This Matrix panel has its own noddy email server which I think is the route of the problem

Comment: The registry entries should probably work. They're specific to the badmail folder of the SMTP service, not to Exchange.

Comment: Do you need to actually accept incoming email at all?  You should be able to adjust your firewall to permit outgoing messages, but not accept anything.

Comment: @Zoredache Unfortunely yes, we lease space on the server to customers, and part of that lease includes some email addresses that match their web domain. Unless there is something that I'm missing I need to let them send and receive mail through our server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Matrix uses port 25 and the default SMTP server was running on port 26 and that was relaying all of the spam. Shut that down and the problem has gone away.

Thanks to everyone who offered their useful advice

Answer (score 1):

Probally your server accepts mail relay.

You should only allow mail relay from within your own domain...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324958/

(I really hope for you, that the person who is installing your new exchange server can help you with this, otherwise I'd think twice to let him do it...)

Comment: Well its me setting up the new server, so its on my head if this problem carries on lol.

Answer (score 1):

*"Possibly not the answer/an answer, but way too long/formatted for a comment"*

I have no idea if this is the "Matrix Control Panel" you mean, but if it is see here: [Matrix Control Panel Software Guide](http://resellers.fasthosts.co.uk/euf/assets/pdf-guides/Fasthosts-Windows-Servers.pdf) and is the Mail settings for **SMTP Relay Status** set to `Enabled (Authenticated)`?

Per the guide:

> SMTP Relay Status: Should normally be set to allow local domains to
> relay mail through the server.
>
> **Disabled:** Stops SMTP traffic
>
> **Enabled (local domains only) :** Will allow only mailboxes hosted on the server
> to send emails
>
> **Enabled (Authenticated) :** Is a more secure option for
> your server as customers will also have to provide their mailbox
> username and password to send email through your server.

I'm not sure what the software is for overall, but it would appear that you need to look at these settings and make sure they are setup correctly for your environment.

Comment: If you have come across Plesk control panel before, its like that but worse. When I started working here about a month ago it was set to open, I changed to authenticated and thought that would be the end of it but we were hit again last night

Comment: If the one I posted isn't it, then I would suggest contacting the company that made the software for support.  But as far as open relays go, the simplest answer is to disable SMTP relay unless you have LOB machines or similar that need to send without a real client software and human interaction (like Outlook/webmail/etc.)

Comment: Sorry, yes the one that you posted is the right one and those are the quotes from the doc that I have here. Trouble is that there is hardle any trace of these people on net

Comment: Is Fasthosts the vendor/OEM?  Can they help?  Honestly, the steps to secure an open relay on any server (if required to do so) is really just to work on things like requiring authentication, only accepting email with valid from addresses, possibly locking down the SMTP server to only allow send connections from specific IPs or subnets (like internal only), etc.  You'll need to start by locking the software down as much as possible for your environment and then going from there.